# How to run declare statement of sql through jdbc?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2, declare

I have a block containing declare begin and end statements which I need to run before doing a process. Presently I am doing it manually in sql developer in IBM db2 database but I need to automate the process with java. So for that I need to run the declare block using jdbc. The block is as follows:

```
DECLARE
    rep_id number(20);
    qz_dt date;
begin
    ou_id='GNDBKSNGH';
    ou_val='1000';
end
/
```

Can anybody please help me out in calling this block through jdbc??

Comment: Just use `Statement.executeUpdate(query);`

Comment: Will it run just like that?? @Ivan

Comment: You might need to replace '/' at the end with ';' but if that SQL code is syntactically correct `executeUpdate(query)` will execute it

Comment: You don't need any terminator at the end of the compound statement, just as you don't need it with simple statements, when executed via the JDBC driver.

Answer (score -1):

You should create a procedure in db2, and then with db2 driver you can execute this procedure

Comment: can u plz give me an example?